# A script on this page may be busy exception

Tags: firefox, exception, webdriver

Everything was fine last few days, but today I have this exception on FF22 :

**A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
Script: file:///C:/Users/VM-AUT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2085126608473413720webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:6047**

I changed values for dom.max_chrome_script_run_time and dom.min_timeout_value but nothing, the problem is still there?
I really don't understand what happens, didnt make any changes on the script, browser is the same (ff 22) ,  no implementations in web site code, everything is absolutely the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The timeout happens in the `fxdriver@googlecode.com`extension, which happens to be the Firefox Driver for selenium. I suggest you report this problem upstream @ http://code.google.com/p/selenium/